# RGB to Ycbcr conversion

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, rgb

I am doing image processing and I have a 3D array with the rgb values of an image and I am trying to convery those values into ycbcr ( I made a copy of the rgb array and called it ycbcr, and

```
public static void rgb2ycbcr(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, ref byte[, ,] arrayrgb, ref byte[, ,] arrayycbcr)
    {

        byte Y;
        byte Cb;
        byte Cr;

        for (int i = 1; i < (bmp.Height + 1); i++)   //don't worry about bmp.height/width+2 its for my project
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < (bmp.Width + 1); j++)
            {
                byte R = arrayrgb[i, j, 0];
                byte G = arrayrgb[i, j, 1];
                byte B = arrayrgb[i, j, 2];

                Y = (byte)((0.257 * R) + (0.504 * G) + (0.098 * B) + 16);
                Cb = (byte)(-(0.148 * R) - (0.291 * G) + (0.439 * B) + 128);
                Cr = (byte)((0.439 * R) - (0.368 * G) - (0.071 * B) + 128);

                arrayycbcr[i, j, 0] = Y;
                arrayycbcr[i, j, 1] = Cb;
                arrayycbcr[i, j, 2] = Cr;

            }
        }

    }
```

the problem is I am not getting the same values for ycbcr as I would get in matlab when I use rgb2ycbcr, is there something missing in my code?

Comment: "not getting the same values for ycbcr as I would get in matlab" What about an example?

Comment: Have tried typing `edit rgb2ycbcr` in the command window to see what Matlab's implementation does?

Comment: yes, an example with a 1x1 image (x3 channels) that gives different results would be very helpful here.

Comment: you may never get the exact value like in Matlab because you are using float calculation. if the values are very close that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Faster and acurate code.
Output values ​​between 0 and 255 (JPG formula)

```
            width = bmp.Width;
            height = bmp.Height;
            yData = new byte[width, height];                     //luma
            bData = new byte[width, height];                     //Cb
            rData = new byte[width, height];                     //Cr

            unsafe
            {
                BitmapData bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
                int heightInPixels = bitmapData.Height;
                int widthInBytes = width * 3;
                byte* ptrFirstPixel = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

                //Convert to YCbCr
                for (int y = 0; y < heightInPixels; y++)
                {
                    byte* currentLine = ptrFirstPixel + (y * bitmapData.Stride);
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        int xPor3 = x * 3;
                        float blue = currentLine[xPor3++];
                        float green = currentLine[xPor3++];
                        float red = currentLine[xPor3];

                        yData[x, y] = (byte)((0.299 * red) + (0.587 * green) + (0.114 * blue));
                        bData[x, y] = (byte)(128 - (0.168736 * red) + (0.331264 * green) + (0.5 * blue));
                        rData[x, y] = (byte)(128 + (0.5 * red) + (0.418688 * green) + (0.081312 * blue));
                    }
                }
                bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert R/G/B to uint before assign.

`uint R =ConvertToUint(arrayrgb[i, j, 0]);`

`uint G =ConvertToUint(arrayrgb[i, j, 1]);`

`uint B =ConvertToUint(arrayrgb[i, j, 2]);`

Comment: Some saturation logic might be needed also.